# What patterns will flash in the native-speaker's brain when using English?

Tags: sentence-patterns, linguistics, esl

I think it is a common puzzle for ESL,especially for Chinese,since English is more abstract than Chinese, using which we can feel some specific patterns flashing in our brain.
For example, when I see 笑(which means smile), I feel it is smiling to me. What do you feel when you see "smile"?

Comment: This is not opinion-based question, I want to find the general thinking pattern of native English speakers

Comment: I have changed the question style to objective one !

Comment: @Lai The concept I associate with 笑 is halfway between a laugh and a smile, so it's not exactly the same as what I associate with *smile* in English, but I think in principle the same kinds of associations are possible with different writing systems.  At least, I don't see any reason why they wouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

> Chinese characters do not constitute an alphabet or a compact syllabary. Rather, the writing system is roughly logosyllabic; that is, a character generally represents one **syllable** of spoken Chinese and may be a word on its own or a part of a polysyllabic word. The characters themselves are often composed of parts that may represent **physical objects**, **abstract notions**,[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Written_Chinese) or pronunciation.[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alphabet)  ([WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Written_Chinese)) [emphasis added]

On the other hand, "(t)he modern English alphabet is a Latin alphabet consisting of 26 letters" ([WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alphabet)), the individual letters or sometimes their combinations (supposedly) representing specific **sounds** of the word's pronunciation.

So you see that Chinese pictographs do indeed represent "things" that one can associate with and recall, English alphabets merely provide a clue to pronunciation, with no relation to the meaning.

Comment: So there is not some pattern in your brain when you see a English word, Even though you are speaking in English??

Comment: @Lai I think the same sorts of associations are possible, but it's difficult to know what you really mean by "patterns flashing in your brain", so it's hard to say, really.

Comment: @snailboat I do know it is hard to say, But I think it is essential to non-native speakers. it is useful to link the native language to English, which means I can learn English using English thinking method. you see?